# langid UpdateRequestProcessor only mapping first field

Tags: solr, solr4, language-detection

I am trying to use solr's  langid UpdateRequestProcessor. Here is the config:

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="languages">
    <processor class="solr.LangDetectLanguageIdentifierUpdateProcessorFactory">
        <lst name="invariants">
            <str name="langid.fl">focus, expertise, platforms, partners, participation, additional</str>
            <str name="langid.whitelist">en,fr</str>
            <str name="langid.fallback">en</str>
            <str name="langid.langField">detectedlang</str>
            <bool name="langid.map">true</bool>
            <bool name="langid.map.keepOrig">false</bool>
        </lst>
    </processor>
    <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

My fields look like this:

```
<fields>
    <field name="_root_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
    <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>

    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />

    <!-- raw fields from sql db -->
    <field name="expertise_id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="person_id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="mod_date" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="lang" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="focus" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="expertise" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="platforms" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="partners" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="participation" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="additional" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="tag" type="text_general" termVectors="true" multiValued="true" />      
    <field name="facet_tag" type="string" stored="false" indexed="false" docValues="true" multiValued="true" default=""/>

    <!-- language detected by solr -->
    <field name="detectedlang" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />

    <!-- defined locale fields -->
    <dynamicField name="*_en" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <dynamicField name="*_fr" type="text_fr" indexed="true" stored="true" />

    <copyField source="tag" target="facet_tag"/>

</fields>
```

When I run an update or a dataimport I know that the "languages" update chain is used because `focus` is mapped to `focus_en` and detectedlang is set.  However, **none of the other fields in `langid.fl` are mapped. Why?**

An example update query:

```
{
  "additional": "here is some other information about me.",
  "expertise_id": "10000",
  "id": "foo_10000",
  "focus": "this is my new focus. It is very exciting. When I am done I expect to be super experienced."
}
```

And here is the result of a query for `expertise_id=10000`. Note that `additional` has not been moved to `additional_en`:

```
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "additional":"here is some other information about me.",
        "expertise_id":10000,
        "id":"foo_10000",
        "detectedlang":"en",
        "focus_en":"this is my new focus. It is very exciting. When I am done I expect to be super experienced.",
        "_version_":1447088846110982144}]
  }
```

Comment: See https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageDetection#Caveats. `Since the implementations uses an n-gram based approach to detection, they are susceptible to poor detection on especially short inputs.` Did you try with longer text?

Comment: @arun: To test the idea that length might be a problem, I just added a document where  all the mapped fields have the identical 200 word English text. `focus` was mapped to `focus_en`. None of the others were mapped.

Comment: @dnagirl, Has any solution been provided?

Comment: @forguta, not that I'm aware. But I haven't been working with Solr recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the problem is a syntax error. This line:

```
<str name="langid.fl">focus, expertise, platforms, partners, participation, additional</str>
```

must be

```
<str name="langid.fl">focus,expertise,platforms,partners,participation,additional</str>
```

The [docs](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageDetection#langid.fl) state that the field list should be comma or space separated values. Evidently, comma and space screws things up (though it works fine in other Solr contexts like `fl` in a requestHandler which langid.fl is supposedly modelled on). I tried the space-separated syntax as well, but it did not fix my issue.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Well, I typed this as a comment for the next thing for you to try yesterday, but thought it is too silly, so did not post it :).